# Is connecting a wallet to a website an on-chain action?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, wallets

I am developing a crypto analytics tool and had this question in mind.
When I connect a wallet to a website (let's imagine I connect metamask to Uniswap), is there anything that happens on-chain that can be tracked? Or is just an offchain action that has no impact on the ethereum ledger of any sorts.

I dont think, so otherwise some sort of gas would need to spend right?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Nothing is recorded on-chain, but the website could track your IP and address.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct no on-chain transaction happens when you connect to a page. If it did you would have to pay gas every time you do so.

Since this would be very expensive the alternative is to use signatures to prove identity without revealing the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a wallet to a website gives the website permission to view details of your wallet. It is only an action in your wallet software, not on-chain.

In MetaMask, at least, it doesn't even give the website permission to make transactions without asking. It only gives the website permission to see your wallet address and read blockchain data.